# SQL : Select table header as tablename and table content as column in view mode

Tags: sql, hive

I am trying to do a select statement which display table name of 2 table with its column and its values  . E.g

i have 2 tables shown below

```
|--- Malaysia
|--- Thailand
```

i am trying to have a new table without the need to create a temp/new table as i only have select privilege's in hive. i was wondering if this is possible with only select statement

e.g view

tablename : **Malaysia**

ot_id and pl_desc is table column

```
|ot_id|pl_desc|
|1223 |3455 |
|3421 |3443|
```

Tablename : **Thailand**
ot_id and etl_desc is table column

```
|ot_id|etl_desc|
|1223 |check |
|3421 |test|
```

im trying to do a select statement which will show tablename and its header as column without the need to create a new table. i was wondering if this is possible

Output should be something like this 
**tablename : temp table**

```
ot_id and pl_desc is table column 
|tablename|columnname|output_value|
|Malaysia |ot_id     |1223|
|Malaysia |ot_id     |3421|
|Malaysia |pl_desc   |3455|
|Malaysia |pl_desc   |3443|
|Thailand |ot_id     |1223|
|Thailand |ot_id     |3421|
|Thailand |etl_desc  |check|
|Thailand |etl_desc  |test|
```

Comment: You should have one, common table for all countries, with a country column. (Similar to your wanted result. `UNION ALL` the current tables.)

Comment: Are the values all strings?  If not, you may have type problems with your approach.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use UNION ALL:

```
select 'Malaysia' as tablename,
       'ot_id' as columnname,
       ot_id as output_value
  from Malaysia
union all
select 'Malaysia' as tablename,
       'pl_desc' as columnname,
       pl_desc as output_value
  from Malaysia
union all
select 'Thailand' as tablename,
       'ot_id' as columnname,
       ot_id as output_value
  from Thailand
union all
select 'Thailand' as tablename,
       'etl_desc' as columnname,
       etl_desc as output_value
  from Thailand
```

Comment: I don't know which RDBMS you use. That's possible that the column aliases are not required after the first select.

Comment: if lets say i have over 100 columns per table , this approach require a very long query ,